# Recursive matrix multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\-1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and is asked to calculate $A^{100}$

It is easy to see that $A^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-n&1\end{pmatrix}$ through calculating the first few $n=1,2,3...$

But I was hoping to set up a function based on the fact that $A^2=2A-I$ to calculate $A^n$. Is that possible?

Edit:

From calculating the first few n=1,2,3... it seems like the function would be:
$$nA-(n-1)I$$

But I am looking to justify it.

Edit 2:

Is this induction proof correct?

$A^n=nA-(n-1)I$ for $n\ge 1$

For $n=1$: $A^1=A-(1-1)I=A$

$A^{n+1}=A(nA-(n-1)I)=nA^2-(n-1)A=n(2A-I)-nA+A=(n+1)A-nI$ which is the initial claim.

Comment: As the identity matrix conmutes with $A$ you can use Newton's formula and you would get $$A^{2n}=(2A-I)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n(2A)^j(-I)^{n-j}=\sum_{j=0}^n(-2)^jA^j$$ Which I don't think is of much help.

Comment: @ラミタ　yes, you do end up with the same problem in the end. But I appreciate the nice formula :)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think you are further ahead in Linear algebra than I am at the moment. I will keep your answer in mind as I continue. Tank you.

Comment: If you don't really understand the first answer to appear, you should not accept it, as this will discourage other people to give an answer. The answer to accept is the one that best helps _you_ to understand the problem (and its possible solutions).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen He wrote something in the comment that I didn't understand. He has since written the answer and deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods lead to
$$
A^n=nA-(n-1)I=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr -n & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The proof is by induction on $n\ge 1$ for both formulas. The first one uses indeed $A^2=2A-I$.

Comment: Yes that works. Tank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware that this is probably not the most natural or best approach, but I just want to explore the idea to use the relation $A^2-2A+I=0$ to evaluate any polynomial in $A$ directly (in particular any power $A^n$), and this without using induction.

Since that relation means that $A$ has an annihilating polynomial $X^2-2X+1=(X-1)^2$, one has for any polynomial $P\in\Bbb C[X]$ and its remainder $R$ after division by $(X-1)^2$, that $P[A]=R[A]$. Since any multiple $M$ of $(X-1)^2$ has both $M[1]=0$ and $M'[1]=0$ for its formal derivative $M'$, and both evaluations are linear in the polynomial concerned, on can characterise $R$ as the unique polynomial of degree${}<2$ with $R[1]=P[1]$ and $R'[1]=P'[1]$, which is easily seen to be $R=P[1]+P'[1](X-1)$.

In particular for $P=X^n$ one gets $R=1+n(X-1)$, so
$$A^n=I+n(A-I)=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}+n\pmatrix{0&0\\-1&0}=\pmatrix{1&0\\-n&1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, write $A=I+B$ and note that $B^2=0$. Then the binomial theorem gives $A^n=I^n+nB=I+n(A-I)=nA-(n-1)I$.